# Opening multiple links in new tabs with one click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, foreach

I have some PHP code:

```
foreach($moduid as $k=>$mod) {
$random = $k+1; 
echo '<a href="http://mysite.com?y='.$cid.'&t='.$mod.'&s=-2" data-pack="true" id="link'.$random.'">data</a>';
}
```

And JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $hash = new Array(); // We create new Array     
$('a').click( function(){ // On each click to <a> element
    if ( $(this).attr("data-pack") == "true" ) { // check wether this is one of the links we use
            $hash[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).attr("href"); // We add href value into $hash object
            $(this).css("color","green"); // Way to mark selected ones
            $(this).attr("data-pack", "selected"); // Change data-pack property value to selected
            return false; // We don't want to execute this yet
    } else if ( $(this).attr("data-pack") == "selected" ) { // In case you change your mind and want to unselect
            $(this).attr("data-pack", "true"); // Change data-pack property back, thanks to Ambrosia pointing it out in the comment
            $(this).css("color","red"); // We mark it as unset
            delete $hash[$(this).attr("id")]; // Remove it from hash
            return false;
    }
});

$("form").submit( function(){ // After we submit
    for (var i in $hash) { // Go trough $hash
            window.open($hash[i]); // And open window for each member
    }
    return false; // We don't actually want to submit form, just open new windows :)
} );        
});
```

I have used some of this: [Open Links in Multiple Browser Windows / Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737592/open-links-in-multiple-browser-windows-tabs)

However it doesn't appear to work, when I click submit. I don't really understand JS and was hoping someone would know why pressing submit doesnt open all these links in new tabs. I'm using this jQuery - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js

It's working in IE8 but not Firefox nor Chrome, I want it to open all links not just ones I've selected. So perhaps this isnt the right JS for the job?

In Firefox it just follows the link.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go unblock popups and your code should work.

Comment: It doesn't. This code works for a one time use, on Opera and IE8. I've tried alot of things on FF and Chrome but no luck. I've edited it a bit: http://pastebin.com/1HsBuix9 and it dont work. I dont want the user to ask whether they want this and that link, they just press submit and it opens all.

Comment: What I'm saying, in not so many words, is that runs against philosophy of browser makers and end users. How are you ensuring that end users are, in fact, wanting to open multiple links? When you can answer that question, you answer your own.

Comment: Because its for a subscribed threads thing, they can open all unread threads with one click...

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<?php
foreach($moduid as $k=>$mod) {
$random = $k+1; 
echo '<a href="http://mysite.com?y='.$cid.'&t='.$mod.'&s=-2" data-pack="true" id="link'.$random.'">data</a>';
}
?>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
alert('asdf');      
$('a').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('target','_blank');
        window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    })
    return false;
} );
```

Worked for me.

Comment: this is not working in chrome , if u guide me whats the solution