# Open multiple windows at same time using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, hyperlink

How can I open multiple windows at same time using javascript and php in a page?
Like someone open all the links at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, it uses javascript.

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://link1.com'); window.open('http://link2.com'); window.open('http://link3.com');">link text</a>
```

Also, a similar topic has been discussed here, might be helpful. [Opening multiple links in new tabs with one click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025553/opening-multiple-links-in-new-tabs-with-one-click)