# Open select link in a new window

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list that is being converted into a select list with jQuery.  Code I am using is pasted below:

```
$("<select />").appendTo(".region .links");
// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": "Links"
}).appendTo(".links select");
$(".links .menu li a").each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
        "value": el.attr("href"),
            "text": el.text()
    }).appendTo(".region select");
});
$(".region select").change(function () {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

This code then generates the following:

```
<select>
<option selected="selected" value="">Links</option>
<option value="http://www.linkvalue.com">Link1</option>
<option value="http://www.linkvalue2.com">Link2</option>
</select>
```

I need to change javascript so that all links open in  new window. How would i go about it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Links in Multiple Browser Windows / Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737592/open-links-in-multiple-browser-windows-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".region select").change(function () {
    window.open(
        this.value,
        '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
     );
});
```

Comment: It works, however, now it opens twice - in the same window and second time in the new/blank window.

Answer (score 0):

Change window.location for that:

```
window.open(
    $(this).find("option:selected").val(),
    '_blank'
);
```

I didn't tested, took the answer from this question : [JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

Comment: I changed it to    $(".region select").change(function() {
     window.open = $(this).find("option:selected").val(),'_blank';
 
   }); and it doesn't work at all now

Comment: Try window.open( info here ) and not window.open = .

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings');
```

instead of

```
window.location
```

which refers to the current window